# How to write a Python f-string with the "plus and minus" symbol in a single line?

Tags: python

The unicode for the plus and minus symbol (±) is `u"\u00B1"`. I can't seem to be able to write submit this unicode with f-string in a single line. See below.

```
>>> print( f'{u"\u00B1"}2 stddev' )
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
```

Instead, I have to do this:

```
>>> plusminus = u"\u00B1"
>>> print( f'{plusminus}2 stddev' )
±2 stddev
```

I would like to write it in a single line. How do I do this with f-string?

For non f-string, I can do this:

```
>>> print( '\u00B12 stddev' )
±2 stddev
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, f-strings directly allow unicode strings, so you don't need to use brackets for this.

Comment: I'm not quite following what you are trying to do. Unicode directly supports unicode, so you can just do ``print("±2")``. Or if you insist on formatting (why?) ``print(f'{"±"}2 stddev')`` will work as well.

Comment: @Gugu72 Thanks... `print( f'\u00B12 stddev' )` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do
`print( f'\u00B12 stddev' )`